# Converting from C++ (GetAsyncKeyState) to C# - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, keypress

I have a new problem with a piece of code from c++. I have a keypress to make a key toggle or something similar...maybe the code will explain better then me :

```
while (1) { 
    Sleep (1);
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB) & 1) { 
    toggle = !toggle; 
if(toggle) 
    {
        code here...();
    }
else 
    {   
        code here...(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In c++ everything is fine...but porting to C# - WPF, is giving me crashes.
Any idea what is the most easy way ?
Thank you,

edit 2 : 
Why isn't working ? I have registered the key for the action..but is not starting.
It's because i am already inside the method ?

`KeyboardHook hook = new KeyboardHook();`
`// take action on keys pressed.
hook.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs>(fireUp);`
`// register the event that is fired after the key press.
hook.RegisterHotKey(ModKeys.None, Keys.Tab);`

```
void fireUp(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
    bool toggle = false;
    toggle = !toggle;
    byte[] byt = { 0xC7,0x83,0x1A,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };
for (int i = 6; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        byt[i] = (byte)(atkSpd & 0xFF);
        atkSpd = atkSpd >> 8;
    }
if (toggle)
    {
        Write(vMemory + 8, byt, 10);
        Write(vMemory, BitConverter.GetBytes((vMemory + 8)), 8);
        Write(atkBase, new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x24, 0x25 }, 3);
        Write(atkBase + 3, BitConverter.GetBytes((vMemory)), 4);
    }
else
    {
      Write(atkBase, new byte[] { 0x66, 0x89, 0xB3, 0x1A, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00 }, 7);
    }
```

}

Comment: Show us the code that crashes that is, show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have many fail codes anyway... This is from WPF, but is not working because i think is just for the MainWindow buttons..: `private void pressTab(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab) {
                rwMem.StartGS();
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Tab) {
                rwMem.StartSW();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i fix it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
private bool toggle = true;
}

private void fireUp(rwKey hotKey)
    {
        byte[] byt ={0xC7,0x83,0x1A,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x48,0x8B,0x74,0x24,
        0x40,0x48,0x8B,0x6C,0x24,0x48,0x48,0x8B,0x5C,0x24,0x50,0x48,0x83,0xC4,0x58,0xC3};
        for (int i = 6; i < 10; ++i) { byt[i] = (byte)(atkSpd & 0xFF); atkSpd = atkSpd >> 8; }

        bool kd = (toggle = !toggle);

        if (kd)
        {
            Write(vMemory + 8, byt, 30);
            Write(vMemory, BitConverter.GetBytes((vMemory + 8)), 8);
            Write(atkBase, new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x24, 0x25 }, 3);
            Write(atkBase + 3, BitConverter.GetBytes((vMemory)), 4);
        }
        else
        {
            Write(atkBase, new byte[] { 0x66, 0x89, 0xB3, 0x1A, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00 }, 7);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you can't use an `KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp` event?

```
private void tabPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        if(toggle) 
        {
            code here...();
        }
        else 
        {   
            code here...(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion this is better approach, not to mention that is more efficient (not checking all the time).

If you want to use the approach you've posted, I'd say that crash happens because the while loop is infinite, not allowing anything else to happen. It would've helped if you provided an exception you get at crash or at least some more info on what actually happens.

Comment: Isn't working the TAB key if i'm not on the wpf window..and i need to make it work in background too.

Comment: Sorry for a bit late response...
With this, I think you're looking for global hotkeys http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/88977/Setting-A-Global-Hot-Key
But I think registering a tab key as global would be a bad idea as it's used in many other windows so it could get messy.

Comment: The code is working great but...it is overwriting the game mapped key and that is very bad. I am still looking for another solution :(

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want to achieve? You've mentioned that you need to make it work in the background. I haven't seen any game which would listen to input even when it's in background, like minimized or behind another window.

Comment: Hm,..with OpenProcess & ModuleCollection i can use the application even if it's in background. I want with my application to be able to press a key and do something in game...like jump or etc.Using RegisterHotKey is great,but it is overwriting the mapped key from in game.Now i'm trying to use GetAsyncKeyState.I will see.I'm not a pro at codding,i'm learning.